# Android Studio: HAX kernel module is not installed

Tags: android, intel, android-virtual-device, haxm

My computer CPU intel Pentium D Processor 925.
 Motherboard is ASUS P5GZ-MX
 I think and research. The CPU doesn't support Android virtual device so I want to change the CPU but I don't know which CPU is solve my problem and suitable my motherboard.
 OR How to fix this error which is shown below with my computer skills?

```
>emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!  
>Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.  
>CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HAXM means `Intel® Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager` which you can find in the `BIOS` as virtualization, first of all make sure your CPU has this feature:

Go to your computer's bios and see if your cpu supports virtualization, if it does then make sure it's enabled and restart saving changes.

Then go to your extra folder in your android installation folder and look for `intel-haxm-android.exe` and run it.

Start Android Studio. It should work now.

**Note:** if your cpu doesn't support virtualization, HAXM won't work, but don't worry you can use `armeabi` instead of intel processor in your android virtual device. It will be much slower though.

Comment: My cpu doesn't support virtualization. Armeabi is working but too slow:) Thank you for your information.

Answer (score 0):

Your CPU is from 2006 and that Pentium model does NOT support VT, so it will not support Intel HAXM. You need to consider using another emulator.Besides the "native" emulation mentioned, you could look into genymotion.